# How to get top 3 (with duplicates)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

mysql server version 5.7.21
mysql workbench version: 6.3

I have made the following query

```
SELECT articles.name as 'Product Name', article_count
FROM
    (select articel_id, count(articel_id) as article_count
    FROM sales_records_row
    GROUP BY  articel_id
    ORDER BY count(articel_id) DESC) 
AS 
    overview,
    articles
WHERE 
    articles.articel_id = overview.articel_id
```

This gives me a tavle that shows me the most bought products. In this fashion

```
Product name         article_count
product3             12
product6             7
product4             5
product2             5
product7             5
product5             3
etc                  etc
```

I would now want to get the top three from this. Including duplicates. So in this case I would get 5 items on my top 3 list since product4, 2 and 7 all are counted 5 times. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql server version 5.7.21 mysql workbench version: 6.3

Comment: Please put limit in subquery LIMIT 3

Comment: @Jaydp adding a LIMIT 3 would just give me three times. Since 3 products have the same count I want all of them to be shown.